# Display title for search engine visitors

Tags: search, google-search, search-engines

I read somewhere*) that there's some `q` part inside the wp_query object, that identifies search engine visitors and shows the keywords they searched for.

I'm currently developing local, so i can't access/see `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->q;`.

Could someone varify if this exists and/or has some alternate solution for retrieving:

- the search engine *name*
- the *search string* searched inside the engine?

*) Can't remember where, but it had something to do with "better search results page" & "hightlighting search terms".

-- **EDIT** --

This is what i got so far:

```
// declare the server itself as invalid to only catch search engine results
$http_referer   = explode( "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
$http_referer   = $http_referer[2];
$home_url       = explode( "/", home_url() );
$home_url       = $home_url[2];

// Coming from a search engine: modify to a search string
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && $home_url !== $http_referer )
{
    // remove previous "s" search query args
    remove_query_arg( 's' );

    $string = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    $query = $string['query'];
    $query = explode( "&", $query );
    foreach ( $query as $q )
    {
        $q = urldecode( $q );
        $arr = explode( "=", $q );
        if ( (string) 'q' === $arr[0] )
            $search_string = $arr[1];
    }

    // build a new "s" search query arg: if isset, from the string entered in the search engines input form
    // in theory that should allow treating it like a normal search result
    // the draw back is, that a search engine visitor would never get directly to a post or page 
    if ( isset( $search_string ) )
        add_query_arg( array( 's' => $search_string ) );
}
```

Aside from the drawback that no search engine visitor would come to a result directly, i wouldn't catch all search engines that way. Google & Altavista got a `q=searchstring` query argument. Yahoo for eg. uses `p=`...

Comment: you could do a check for a few known hosts: `$isgoogle = strpos($string['host'],'google');` then grab the appropriate string for that host.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test on my hosted dev site. I ran the following:

```
echo '<pre>';
global $wpdb;
print_r($wpdb);
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo '</pre>';
```

There was no 'wp_query', '[q]', or 'search' variables to be found. Note that I was not able to search this through a search engine as it's not web accessible.

Just to give you a little more, here is the whole object I get: http://pastebin.com/qV2QSHYf.

Comment: Wow, mate! That's nice even if it didn't bring anything up. +1

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard this of wp_query, but could you look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get this? I've never tried personally.

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) )
    print_r( parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) );
```

Comment: I just ran a test on google and got this result, so i guess it should be that way `http://www.google.at/search?q=test+me+now`

Comment: you can use php's parse_url() to get the host and query. edited my answer to add some code.

Comment: the problem is, that i'd have to decide what `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is a valid external referer - or somehow deny localhost and/or the server url. When `print_r`-ing the http referer i also get for ex. `http://localhost/wordpress/?s=test`. So far i could filter out the search string from a google search, but i'm really not sure about how to get the search string from _any_ engine displayed as search result. I'll update your answer to show you the "so far how-to" (which is not satisfying).